# req.body returns an empty object eventhough data is passed through form

Tags: node.js, express

this is my index.js code and it returns an empty object even though data is passed on from the front-end

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

app.post("/api/register", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.json({ status: "ok" });
});

app.listen(8000, () => {
  console.log("listening on port 8000 . . . ");
});
```

Comment: Tried the request with this command and it printed the json passed in the body successfully: `curl -v -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"par":"val"}' -X POST localhost:8000/api/register`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main reason this does not work is
some how the data passed in body is in text format while `req.body` is
expecting json data
make sure to double chek the `'Content-Type':'application/json'` is set on the request `headers`

Comment: This helped me, i was busy sending body as text instead of json on postman

Answer (score 3):

For the specific case you're talking about, you usually need oa body parser to be able to access the form input fields. The minimum example that I advice you to build above it is the following:

```
// parse requests of content-type - application/json
app.use(express.json());

// parse requests of content-type - application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

Some other hints

Make sure that the request is being submitted with the header Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded or Content-Type: application/json
Check if there any CORS problems
Here's More [reference](https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/express/body#:%7E:text=Express%20has%20a%20built-in%20express.json%20%28%29%20function%20that,parsed%20request%20body%2C%20use%20req.body%20as%20shown%20below.) for you

Answer (score 1):

if you are using `multipart/form-data` or require a file upload from frontend you will need a `multer` as middleware for your post/patch requests, otherwise you can set your frontend to send `application/json`

[edit]
this line looks missing from your index.js

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}))
```

Comment: 'Content-Type' : 'application/json' has already been set on front end still the same issue even when i test it using postman

Comment: I've edited my answer to include urlencoded setup for express try adding that it should work

Comment: still returns an empty object on req.body

Answer (score 0):

We can use the body-parser middleware as below:

1. $ npm install body-parser --> install package
2. const bodyParser = require('body-parser'); --> import package